# Visual Studio C# console app doesn't let me specify configuration (also all options are empty)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, console-application

I haven't opened a Console Application in a hot minute but now I need it to run some benchmarks / complete an intake assignment. This is embarrassing, but I can't even get it set up right, and it's not like I'm a newbie.

[image: sexy image]

I'm not doing anything special, it's just empty. Properties of the Solution are also completely empty, so that doesn't help much either.

[image: props]

Interestingly enough it didn't even include all language features, e.g. `var span = "My String".AsSpan();` doesn't work.

Lastly I have .NET desktop development installed with .NET 7 included. Really confused as to what's wrong.

Steps to recreate:

1. Launch VS 2022 (17.7.5)
2. Create a new project
3. Console App C#
4. Next
5. Create

Comment: Not being able to specify the configuration also disallows me from adding NuGet packages, so I can't install the BenchmarkDotNet package I'd like to use.

It's days like this I should have been a farmer.

Comment: Your solution doesn't actually have any projects at the moment - note the "0 projects" in Solution Explorer. That's why you can't specify a configuration, or indeed do *anything* with a project, because there's no project in the solution. I've just been through your exact "steps to recreate" and ended up with a solution with a single project...

Comment: Note how your C# file is in "Miscellaneous Files" rather than in a project, too...

Comment: Adding the project manually gives an error "The ... package did not load correctly."

Comment: @CaseyHofland: *"The ... package did not load correctly."* - It sounds like **that** may be the real problem to investigate here.  The picture in the question shows that there are no projects, so there's nothing to run/debug.  If your project is failing to load in some way, we'd need information about that problem.  Alternatively, what happens when you just create a new project and paste your code into it?

Comment: The same thing, I can create a new project but it won't link it. I'll investigate the package error, now that I know a little more.

Comment: close the app, and re-open it as `Administrator` see if that would help, if not, maybe you need to uninstall and then reinstall VS all together.

Comment: I'd also try to use the command line to create a new project. "dotnet new console" in any folder should create a working project.

Comment: Silly me, reinstalling fixed everything. You'd think I'd know my software by now. If you'll submit the answer I'll flag it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm glad you were able to resolve the issue by reinstalling Visual Studio. This really shows that you are extremely lucky. Because usually reinstalling may not solve this issue.

The reason for saying this is because this issue is usually caused by a problem with the dotnet environment variables. To prove what I'm saying, I need to reproduce your problem first, like this:

[image]

Then the correct solution to this issue is:

You can modify the environment variables and find the path "This PC -> Right click 'Properties' -> Advanced system settings -> Environment Variables –> System variables –> double click path"-> Delete "C:\Program Files (x86) \dotnet" and make sure there is "C:\Program Files\dotnet".

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Of course, it may also be because "C:\Program Files\dotnet" is not the correct path. This requires you to find the correct installation location of your dotnet and modify it.

Finally, when your dotnet environment variables are configured correctly, you will find that everything is normal when you re-create a console program.